# Instagram API - Redirect Uri in my app

Tags: android, redirect, uri, instagram

I am trying to use instagram api in my android app and they use oauth2 for authentication. They want me to provide a redirect uri. I have researched both stackoverflow and google but still don't understand what to do.

ps.. don't have a webpage or sth.

Comment: I think redirect uri is just a URL( with proper path prefix to validate the users action from a web page into application like www.redirecturi.com/success or  www.redirecturi.com/failure. Correct me if if i am wrong .

Comment: Do you mean that I should give a path to open the application? How do we do that?

Comment: No not to open application. This setting must be set at developer console of instagram. If you are using webView for intagram authorization then this URI will be return in WebClient .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect URL is meant to be used by Instagram upon a successful login through their site.

From their [documentations](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

> [Upon successful authentication] The server will redirect the user in one of two ways that you choose:
>
> - Server-side flow (recommended): Redirect the user to a URI of your choice. Take the provided code parameter and exchange it for an access_token by POSTing the code to our access_token url.
> - Implicit flow: Instead of handling a code, we include the access_token as a fragment (#) in the URL. This method is less secure, but allows applications without any server component to receive an access_token.

Judging by your question, you don't currently have the necessary backend to utilize the server-side flow described above.

Hence you're left with the option of doing it "implicitly" which doesn't strictly require a redirect URL. Knowing this, **it should be safe to put any string within the Redirect URL field**.

Comment: You are right, i don't currently have a backend. Thanks a lot i will try second flow.

Comment: You're welcome! Also, it would be extremely helpful to mark this answer as accepted if it's indeed what you're looking for. :)

Comment: I didn't want to mark accepted before trying it :) is it possible to give a redirect uri to switch back to application from browser? I think i might need a webpage for that...

Comment: Fair enough! Yes it is indeed possible. What you want to do is basically listen for the response IG's authentication page will make and see if the whole process was successful. You could create a custom `WebViewClient` which listens and acts on responses from IG and assign it to your `WebView`. Head here for more: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html.